# Разделение выпуклого многоугольника(полигона) на 2 фигуры отрезком,прямой

Tags: c#, c++, геометрия

Доброго вечера.
Имеется выпуклый многоугольник заданный `point *polygon_ = new point;` в массиве точек, он разделяется отрезком,точки пересечения хранятся в другом массиве `dot_intersections[4];` состоящем из 4 элементов т.к. точек всего 2 `(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x,p2.y)`. Как можно "координатно" выделить 2 полученные фигуры, после разделения многоугольника прямой, если необходимая информация, в принципе имеется?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблемы особой быть не должно. Проходите по циклу по отрезкам-сторонам, смотрите, какой из них пересекает прямую. Если никакой, алгоритм окончен.

Первая вершина нового многоугольника №1 — точка пересечения. Начиная от первого отрезка, который пересекает прямую, снова обходите ваши стороны по циклу. До следующей точки пересечения вершины старого прямоугольника одновременно являются вершинами и нового многоугольника №1. Далее, следующая точка пересечения — последняя вершина нового многоугольника №1 и одновременно первая вершина нового многоугольника №2. Ну и так далее.

Продолжайте сканировать, пока не придёте к исходной, первой точке пересечения.

P. S.: Выяснить, пересекает ли отрезок прямую, просто. Например, если прямая задана в виде уравнения `Ax + By + C = 0`, сравните знаки величин `Ax1 + By1 + C` и `Ax2 + By2 + C`, где (x1, y1) и (x2, y2) — концы отрезка.

---

Ну вот код на C#. Для начала, набросаем вспомогательные типы данных и операции над ними.

Точка и вектор:

```
class Point
{
    public readonly double X, Y;
    public Point(double x, double y) { X = x; Y = y; }
    public static Vector operator - (Point end, Point start) =>
        new Vector(end.X - start.X, end.Y - start.Y);
    public static Point operator +(Point from, Vector by) =>
        new Point(from.X + by.X, from.Y + by.Y);
    public static bool operator ==(Point p1, Point p2) => p1.X == p2.X && p1.Y == p2.Y;
    public static bool operator !=(Point p1, Point p2) => !(p1 == p2);
}

class Vector
{
    public readonly double X, Y;
    public Vector(double x, double y) { X = x; Y = y; }
    public Vector Rotate90() => new Vector(Y, -X);
    public double ScalarProduct(Vector other) => X * other.X + Y * other.Y;
    public static Vector operator *(Vector v, double k) => new Vector(v.X * k, v.Y * k);
}
```

Прямая и отрезок:

```
class Line
{
    public readonly Point Start;
    public readonly Vector Direction;
    public readonly Vector Normal;
    public Line(Point start, Point end)
    {
        Start = start;
        Direction = end - start;
        Normal = Direction.Rotate90();
    }
    public Line(Segment segment) : this(segment.Start, segment.End) { }
    public double OrientedDistance(Point point) => (point - Start).ScalarProduct(Normal);
}

class Segment
{
    public readonly Point Start, End;
    public Segment(Point start, Point end) { Start = start; End = end; }
}
```

Многоугольник:

```
class Polygon
{
    public readonly Point[] Points;
    public readonly Segment[] Sides;

    public Polygon(IEnumerable<Point> points)
    {
        Points = points.ToArray();
        int n = Points.Length;
        Sides = new Segment[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Sides[i] = new Segment(Points[i], Points[(i + 1) % n]);
    }
}
```

Покамест всё тривиально. Теперь сам алгоритм.

```
static IEnumerable<Polygon> SplitPolygonByLine(Polygon poly, Line line)
{
    int n = poly.Sides.Length;
    int startIndex;
    for (startIndex = 0; startIndex < n; startIndex++)
    {
        if (LineIntersectsSegment(poly.Sides[startIndex], line))
            break;
    }
    if (startIndex == n)
    {
        // нет пересечения, результат = весь многоугольник, выходим
        yield return poly;
        yield break;
    }

    Segment currentSide = poly.Sides[startIndex];
    Point firstIntersection = GetLineIntersection(new Line(currentSide), line);
    List<Point> currentPoints = new List<Point>() { firstIntersection, currentSide.End };

    int currentIndex = (startIndex + 1) % n;
    while (currentIndex != startIndex)
    {
        currentSide = poly.Sides[currentIndex];
        if (LineIntersectsSegment(currentSide, line))
        {
            // нашли пересечение?
            Point currentIntersection = GetLineIntersection(new Line(currentSide), line);
            if (currentIntersection != currentSide.Start)
                currentPoints.Add(currentIntersection);
            // заканчиваем текущий многоугольник
            yield return new Polygon(currentPoints);
            // и начинаем новый
            currentPoints = new List<Point>();
            if (currentIntersection != currentSide.Start)
                currentPoints.Add(currentIntersection);
        }
        currentPoints.Add(currentSide.End);
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % n;
    }

    // закончили круг? добавляем стартовую вершину к последнему многоугольнику
    if (firstIntersection != currentPoints.Last())
        currentPoints.Add(firstIntersection);
    yield return new Polygon(currentPoints);
}
```

Остались вспомогательные функции `LineIntersectsSegment` и `GetLineIntersection`.

```
static bool LineIntersectsSegment(Segment segment, Line line)
{
    double d1 = Math.Sign(line.OrientedDistance(segment.Start));
    double d2 = Math.Sign(line.OrientedDistance(segment.End));
    return d1 != d2 && d2 != 0;
}

static Point GetLineIntersection(Line l1, Line l2)
{
    // l1.Start + X * l1.Direction belongs to l2 <=>
    // l1.Start + X * l1.Direction - l2.Start || l2.Direction <=>
    // (l1.Start + X * l1.Direction - l2.Start).Scalar(l2.Normal) == 0 <=>
    // (l2.Start - l1.Start).Scalar(l2.Normal) = X * l1.Direction.Scalar(l2.Normal)
    double coeff = l1.Direction.ScalarProduct(l2.Normal);
    if (coeff == 0) // прямые не пересекаются
        throw new ArgumentException("прямые не пересекаются");
    double x = (l2.Start - l1.Start).ScalarProduct(l2.Normal) / coeff;
    return l1.Start + l1.Direction * x;
}
```

Если я ничего не напутал, должно работать.

(Да, я не особо вдумывался в хитрые случаи наподобие «прямая проходит через угол».)

Comment: На словах алгоритм то понятен, не получается программная реализация, точки пересечения будем считать, что по дефолту у нас имеются. это массив `dot_intersections[4];`, как стоит действовать относительно координат по x,y в цикле?

Comment: @LokenGarvel': Нет, «точки пересечения имеются» — это не то. Вам нужны на каждом шагу точки пересечения _отрезка_ с _прямой_. А то как иначе вы сообразите, какая из точек пересечения чему соответствует?

Comment: @ VladD, понял. Получается примерно следующее `for (int i = 0; i < R.size_polygon; i++)
 {
  if (R.polygon_[i].y < dot_intersections[1]);
  if (R.polygon_[i].y < dot_intersections[3])
  {
   
   cout << " (" << R.polygon_[i].x << "),(" << R.polygon_[i].y << ") " << endl;
   
  }
 }`

Comment: @LokenGarvel': Не, не так. Существующий массив `dot_intersections` полностью бесполезен, не используйте его. Вы должны **на каждом шагу** вычислить точку пересечения отрезка-стороны с прямой.

Comment: @LokenGarvel': Сейчас набросаю код на C#.

Comment: @ VladD, будем теперь разбираться, про мои костыли могли и не упоминать =))

Comment: @LokenGarvel': Набросал код, смотрите. Сейчас я тоже потестирую.

Comment: @LokenGarvel': Нашёл один баг, я не увеличивал индекс в цикле. Исправил. (`currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % n;`). И ещё `currentSide = poly.Sides[currentIndex];` (а было `startIndex`).

Comment: @LokenGarvel': Поисправлял случаи, когда прямая проходит через вершину. Не смотрел, что будет, если прямая совпадает с одной из сторон.

Comment: @ VladD, не получается у меня разобраться с кодом на шарпе, лямбда операторы мне вообще не понятны . Если бы я мог предоставить свой код на плюсах, вы могли бы тыкнуть меня носом в участок где я должен по новой вычислить точку пересечения? т.к. с задачей нахождения пересечения я справился.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68875/discussion-between-lokengarvel-and-vladd).